# Chrome extension for Google Shared Drive Changes

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to enforce naming schemes for Google Shared Drives. Is it possible to create an extension that has a pop up occur when someone changes the name of a specific folder or file in a Google Shared/Team drive?

Comment: Extensions don't have an API for this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am seeing Google has push notifications for Drive API. Is there a way I can utilize this for pop ups on file change? Ex. User changes file > push notification is sent > Extension receives notification > Create pop up based on what notification is.